# Jquery Validate with regular expressions

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery validate with a regular expressions.

```
 $("#RentalApplication_CompanyRegNumber").rules("add", { regex: "^(19|20)[\d]{2}\/[\d]{6}\/23$" })
```

I am trying to validate South African company registration numbers.

1978/123456/23  valid

2021/666666/23  valid

I have tested it in a regular expression tester but it does not validate properly in jquery validate.

The code is definitely adding the rule but the regex is not validating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#RentalApplication_CompanyRegNumber").rules("add", { regex: /^(19|20)[\d]{2}\/[\d]{6}\/23$/ })
```

I Just changed the format until I got it right.

removed the " and replaced with /

Comment: And what is the difference between of provided  code of lines?

Comment: I removed the quotes(") and replaced with /